# Get Size of Folder Containing Hardlinks (like Time Machine Backups)

Tags: time-machine, filesystem, macos

I'm using an `rsync` script to make incremental backups of a specific folder, in very much the same way `Time Machine` does. I'm very interested to know how large my backup destination folder is. However when I `Get Info` in the `Finder`, it tells me the size as if each hardlink is it's own unique file.

Is there a way I can calculate the actual disk space used by a folder, where hard-linked files aren't being counted again and again for each link?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118203/how-to-get-folder-size-ignoring-hard-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, partially assisted by the comment above, is to use `du`

Specifically, 
`du -hs /path/to/folder/i/want/to/get/size/of`

This counts hardlinked files only once. This is the parent folder of my hard-linked backups. So Finder tells me ~322 MB but `du` tells me ~171 MB. I don't think the 1000 vs 1024 issue is taken into account, but it's certainly close enough for my needs!

Comment: I'm actually getting the same result as I would with the Finder with this command on macOS Big Sur